# Why does PIT fail to pick up my test class for my production class?

Tags: java, pitest

I am trying to make [PIT](https://pitest.org/) run for a Spring/Maven-based Java project, but get strange results. My first runs show an overwhelming number of `TIMED_OUT`s for all sorts of mutations. [The general recommendations in their FAQ](https://pitest.org/faq/), such as increasing the timeout settings, didn't yield any improvements.

So I picked out one sample to analyze what's happening: `StringUtilities` is a plain class with some `static` methods that perform simple string manipulations, such as trimming whitespace, etc. I entered `<targetClasses><param>**.StringUtilities</param></targetClasses>` to focus this class alone.

The surprising observation was that PIT's report listed tens of test classes in the "Tests examined" section that it ran. However, the most important one, `StringUtiltiesTest`, the unit test class that was specifically written for this live class, was *not* included. To verify, I entered it as `<targetTests><param>**.StringUtilitiesTest</param></targetTests>`, and indeed, PIT said it couldn't find any test and calculated 0% mutation coverage.

The obvious thing to do was checking the class path, but I cannot see anything strange about it. The preceeding Maven build picks the test class up alright. The project uses a standard main/test folder structure, and the class is located in the live package's test mirror.

One thing I did notice was that my test suite consists of a mix of JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests. The project is migrating to the newer version, but piece by piece, over a course of several weeks or months. StringUtilitiesTest is JUnit 5.

Does PIT have problems with such a version mixture? Are there other possible explanations why the test class isn't picked up?

Comment: Do you have the pitest junit5 plugin installed?

Comment: Indeed, you need to use the [Junit-5 plugin](https://github.com/pitest/pitest-junit5-plugin). Not sure however how it behaves with JUnit Vintage.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I've been using `<plugin><groupId>org.pitest</groupId><artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId><version>1.7.6</version><configuration>...</configuration></plugin>`. Will check.

Comment: Using the JUnit 5 plugin fixed it. If you care to turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.